# Should I upgrade linux-headers-generic, linux-image-generic?

Tags: installation, upgrade, synaptic

I used the 12.04 minimal installation image/ CLI installer to install the base operating system.  Once the base system was installed I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

At this point there were system upgrades which were downloaded and applied.  I went on to install xorg nvidia-current gdm gnome-shell synaptic.  Every step of the way I'd check for "upgrades" and after the initial bout of upgrades nothing was ever upgraded.

Once I rebooted, logged into the gnome desktop environment and started synaptic, however, on Mark All Upgrades Synaptic said:

```
To be upgraded
   linux-headers-generic
   linux-image-generic
```

It seems like that should've been upgraded during the installation, yes?  But I'm using ppa which draw software newer than that which is available in Synaptic.

Will I downgrade the ppa installations I've already applied to the system by running the aforementioned upgrade through synaptic?

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That would take care of everything. As a general rule, you should not upgrade the kernel yourself.

Comment: These kernel updates are unexpected and they're being offered through Synaptic immediately following a successful fresh install during which no further kernel updates were available at the command line.  Should I still install them?